# Почему canvas не рисует?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Я пытаюсь нарисовать на canvas что-либо, у меня есть такой код:

```
let mouseDown = false;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e: MouseEvent) => {
         if(!mouseDown) {
           mouseDown = true;
           ctx!.beginPath();
         }
         
          ctx!.moveTo(e.pageX - (e.target as HTMLCanvasElement).offsetLeft, e.pageY - (e.target as HTMLCanvasElement).offsetTop);
          ctx!.lineTo(e.pageX - (e.target as HTMLCanvasElement).offsetLeft, e.pageY - (e.target as HTMLCanvasElement).offsetTop);
          ctx!.stroke();
       });
```

Почему canvas ничего не отображает(рисует)?

Comment: потому что линия из себя в себя

Comment: @Grundy, не очень понял, можете объяснить поподробнее?

Comment: ты переходишь в точку (x,y) и говоришь, а теперь проведи линию в (x,y)

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае происходит попытка провести линию в точку, в которой уже находится курсор.

Для решения достаточно изменить хотя бы одну из координат.

Однако, логичнее было бы запоминать начальную точку [при нажатии мыши](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event), и рисовать линию только если кнопка мыши нажата.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mouseDown = false;
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  mouseDown = true;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.pageX - (e.target).offsetLeft, e.pageY - (e.target).offsetTop);
})

document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
})
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!mouseDown) {
    return;
  }

  ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - (e.target).offsetLeft, e.pageY - (e.target).offsetTop);
  ctx.stroke();


});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ с разъяснением! Я так понял moveto только ставит начальную точку.

Comment: @user469485, вообще он перемещает перо в нужную точку без контура. но конкретно в примере - да, просто ставит начальную точку

Comment: Теперь все встало на свои места. Спасибо

Comment: Я понимаю что вопрос уже решен и закрыт, но у меня возник небольшой вопрос, что делать если при выходе за пределы canvas с зажатой кнопкой мыши, то при возвращении на canvas он продолжает рисовать. Как это исправить? Буду очень благодарен ответу

Comment: @user469485, не понял вопрос.